# Pass in a float to np.linspace

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code:

```
dt     = .001   # simulation time step (seconds)
T      = 1.0    # total time to simulate (seconds)
time   = np.linspace(dt,T,dt/T)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
time   = np.linspace(dt,T,dt) # vector of timepoints we will simulate
```

I am writing the code in a PyCharm IDE using a Conda virtual environment to provide a little more context. Thank in advance!

Comment: maybe `np.linspace(dt, T, int(T/dt))`.

Comment: The point of using `numpy.linspace` is to *avoid* the use of a floating-point step. Computing things in terms of `dt` sacrifices the benefit of `numpy.linspace`. Work in terms of a step count, not a step size.

Comment: I would like to keep the value as a float if possible. Thanks for the clarification i will add that to the question as well.

Comment: You are getting this error because the third parameter of linspace is `num` which requires a integer not a float. If you try to convert it to an int you would round it down to zero which wouldn't return anything. Are you sure you do not want `T/dt` instead because aren't you trying to find the number of steps to take. So it would be the amount of time divided by the time steps? If that's right then just do `time   = np.linspace(dt,T,int(T/dt))` That should work.

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do actually corresponds to [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html).

```
time = np.arange(dt, T, dt)
```

To include the `T` time you will need to change the stop boundary to `T + dt`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dwight in the comments, but I thought I could tell you anyway, just to give you another option, that numpy.arange(start, stop, step) may be also useful to you, and should do the same trick.